# How to change the icon of XAMPP Control Panel

Tags: icons, xampp

I recently installed XAMPP and added the shortcut to my application menu as shown below:

[image: Application Menu with XAMPP icon]

But after launching the application, the icon in the dock goes missing (Refer image below):

[image: Ubuntu dock with missing XAMPP icon]

On clicking the application in the menu it runs **/opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run**

> How do I add a xampp.png icon to this *.run* application?

**Edit:** Tbh, the application menu icon has nothing to do with this . The same thing  happens when you open the control panel through terminal:

```sh
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```